# Why secure parameter in setCookie() does not have effect?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

`setcookie("samplecookiename", "sampledata", time()+3600*24*10, '/', 'domain.com', TRUE, TRUE);`

This syntax sets the cookie in name samplecookiename with data sampledata with expiry date perfectly. But still I see the cookie is available for all type of connections. What is the issue? The PHP version used in the website is 5.3.27 and in localhost 5.3.8.

Any ideas?

[image]

Update: The cookie is also accessible by scripts too. Means the cookie is not set as HTTP only.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Cookies - HTTP & HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289867/google-chrome-cookies-http-https)

Comment: @BartPlatak: I believe it is not. I use the syntax which was accepted there as answer. It does not work.

Comment: Did you try it with an empty cookie jar? And are you accessing the page via HTTPS?

Comment: @Gumbo: I found the issue and posted as an answer. But any idea why the cookie is not set to secure when inside another page which was included by PHP? (Refer my answer).

Comment: Whether `setcookie` is called in the main file or an included file doesn’t matter.

Comment: Yeah but the same line of code if placed directly in the main page it works as expected.

Comment: Just make sure [you still can change the HTTP header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/53114).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you are using Chrome as your browser.

Comment: ...and how does this relate to the question exactly?